# Javascript .split() a string for each number of characters

Tags: javascript, string

I have a variable that holds a number

```
var simpleNumber = 012345678;
```

I want to `.split()` this number and create an array that would be of each 3 numbers

the array should look like this

```
[012, 345, 678]

var splitedArray = simpleNumber.toString().split(/*how do i split this?*/);
```

it is part of a getRGB("ffffff") function, so i cant know what will be passed in.

Thanks

Comment: A leading 0 in javascript creates a number in octal. If it is important, you need to represent it as a string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try:

```
var splittedArray = "012345678".match(/.../g);

function tridigit(n) {
    return n.toString().match(/.{1,3}/g);
}
```

Note that if you prefix a number with a zero, it will be interpreted in octal. Octal literals are officially deprecated, but are supported for the time being. In any case, numbers don't have leading zeros, so it won't appear when you convert the number to a string.

Testing on Safari and FF, numbers with a leading 0 and an 8 or 9 are interpreted in base 10, so octal conversion probably wouldn't be a problem with your specific example, but it would be a problem in the general case.

Comment: Note that this won't work as you expect if the number starts with a zero, as the zero disappears.

Comment: Also, the leading 0 will turn the number into octal.

Comment: Oh, I see, any solution for a case that it starts with a 0

Comment: Will not work if the number is not a multiplication of 3 (in this case).

Comment: will i have to check if the leading no. is not a 0, and if yes increment it?  is that a solution?

Comment: @adardesign: Positional number systems have an infinite number of 0 digits running to the left of the numeral. Because they contribute nothing to the value the numeral, they're left out. If you want zeros, you'll have to figure out how many you want to add, because any other way isn't well defined.

Comment: @adardesign: You need to better define what numbers you're working with. Is it just 12345678, or any number?

Comment: it is part of a getRGB("ffffff") function, so i cant know what will be past in.

anyway, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var num = 123456789+"";// converting the number into string
var x1=num[0]+num[1]+num[2];//storing the individual values
var y1=new Array(x1);// creating a first group out of the first 3 numbers
var x2=num[3]+num[4]+num[5];
var y2=new Array(x2);// creating a second group out of the next 3 numbers
var x3=num[6]+num[7]+num[8];
var y3=new Array(x3);// creating a third group out of the next 3 numbers
var result=y1.concat(y2,y3);// concat all the 3 array
document.write(result);you get the output in the form of array
document.write("<br/>");
document.write(result[0]);
document.write("<br/>");
document.write(result[1]);
document.write("<br/>");
document.write(result[2]);
```

check the below link for the working example http://jsfiddle.net/informativejavascript/c6gGF/4/

Comment: Thanks for your answer (and the explaining comments), But what makes you think that this solution is better then the above ones..

Comment: Thanks adardesign, the solutions provided by others are absolutely fine, its just that I wanted to imply a different approach in this issue.