# Reverse characters in a string based on a number and string passed into a function

Tags: javascript, string

Im trying to create a function that will split characters and reverse the characters in a string based on the number passed into the function . I get hung up on combining the reversed characters back together and returning the value.

```
function spinCharN(string, number) {
      var group1 = string.split('');
      var group2 = [];
      var group3;

      return group1.forEach(function (str) {
        group2.push(str);

       if (group2.length === number) {
          group3 += (group2.reverse(''));//this is where the debugger informs me of my mistake

          group2 = [];
        }
      });
    return group3;
    }
    result = spinCharN('original choco tacos?', 3);

console.log(result)  
// => ironig laohc occat?so
```

Is there also a cleaner/functional/better way to flip the characters?

Comment: You haven't really explained what your code to do. In what way is the number expected to be used to reverse the characters in the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use [Javascript .split() a string for each number of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1953282/1529630) to split the string into groups
2. Reverse each group
3. Join all groups

```js
function spinCharN(string, number) {
  if (number >>> 0 !== number) throw Error('Invalid number');
  var groups = string.match(new RegExp('.{1,'+number+'}', 'g')) || [''];
  return groups.map(function (str) {
    return str.split('').reverse().join('');
  }).join('');
}
console.log(spinCharN('original choco tacos?', 3));
```

Comment: Thank you. Out of curiousity why did you use, >>>, zero-fill right shift bitwise operator? I tried searching for an explanation on SO, mdn and none of the resources made any sense to me. Also, do you have any resources you can point me to regarding use cases for bitwise operators?

Comment: sorry for the multiple notifications too. I just learned [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: @Alt-RockNinjaCowgirl Well, `>>>` here is kind of a quick hack to prevent regex injection vulnerabilities. `number >>> 0` returns `ToUint32(number)`, that is, converts to unsigned 32-bit integer. The comparison ensures `number` is an integer in the range 0...4294967295 (inclusive). Probably something like `Number.isInteger(number) && number > 0` would be better. Not sure which exact range is supported in JS regex quantifiers.